# Unable to Override the new AccountContactRelation standard page with custom VF Page

Tags: visualforce, standardlayout

I have created a new custom VF Page for `AccountContactRelation` object for creating a new record that's because of Custom Lookup dialog for Contact. But i am unable to override the Standard `AccountContactRelation` page as there is no New button under the “Button, links & Actions” section where we can override the Visualforce page for New button.

[image]

Comment: One option could be remove the related list and add page as inline.

Comment: From where do we need to remove the related list are you referring to related list on Account Page?

Answer (score 0):

`AccountContactRelation` (`ACR` for short) is a 'special' SObject, by which I mean that Salesforce appears to have implemented it in a way that it doesn't have the the complete 'standard' set of customizations that we can apply to an SObject.

You're correct in saying that to completely override a standard action (like creating a new record), we'd need to go to the object's Buttons, Links, and Actions, and override there. As you've noted, there are no Buttons, Links, or Actions defined on `ACR` (at least, none that we can see).

The closest that you'll be able to get to overriding the 'New' page for `ACR` is to do the following:

- Create a new List button for `ACR`, and point it to your Visualforce page
- Go to `Account` and `Contact` layouts
- Edit the `ACR` related list in each layout to remove the 'New Relationship' button
- Add your custom List button to the related list

This won't prevent people who can url-hack from seeing the standard 'new `ACR`' page (`/<ACR Id prefix>/e` still goes to the standard page), but it should ensure that the vast majority of your users use the page you intend.